# How to install 32 bit library to 32 bit web application running on 64 bit machine?

Tags: asp.net, iis

I'm trying to install a library that calls a separate dll, so I have 2 dll files.  Lets call them `library.dll` and `dependency.dll` respectively.

If both are 32 bit I get the following error:

`Unable to load DLL 'dependency.dll': The specified module could not be found.`

If they are both 64 bit, I get the following:

`An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)`

I'm guessing `library.dll` needs to be 32 bit, because the application is 32 bit, but `dependency.dll` needs to be 64 bit because the machine is 64 bit.  Not sure if that's how it works, but I can't get this library to work.  Any suggestions?

Comment: how are you loading the 32-bit dll?  maybe it just can't find the dll.  Use process monitor to see where it is looking for the dll.  if you think it is a dependency issue instead, can use a dependency checker like https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies to see if there are any complaints.  did you build both dlls on your computer?

Comment: did you try to set a 32-bit application to enable set to true in iis application pool advance setting? [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NEKG1.png)